# Fullscreen YouTube Video as Background without Share/Watch Later/Icon/Start Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, youtube

```js
import React from "react";
import tree from "../components/tree";

function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div className="screen">
    <div className="videoContainer">
      <iframe className="videoContainer_video" width="1920" height="1080" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ByG3b0nIT_M?modestbranding=1&control=0&autoplay=1&showinfo=0&autohide=1&modestbranding=1&fs=0&loop=1&rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HomePage;
```

```css
.videoContainer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%
}

.screen {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -99;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]I'm working on a project that needs to use YouTube video as fullscreen background when user visits the page, I read through a lot of articles and tried, but I am only able to remove the control bar, not the icon of the left, share and watch later on the right, and the start button on the center, I'm using react on the project, basically just need the page to load with video as fullscreen background, nothing else, can somebody help please?  Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is because by default the youtube embedding links have these features automatically build-in. You can see this by visiting [this](https://www.youtube.com/embed/ByG3b0nIT_M) /embed/ example. So, in short you need to update your src link or just use something like CSS selectors to ignore the button tags that coorespond with the following classes: `ytp-share-button` and `ytp-watch-later-button`. You could do something like this...

```
.ytp-share-button {
  display:none
}
```